# How to count the number of occurences of a child within a tag?

Tags: php

i am new in php. As an intern, I have to populate a database in MySQL using data from XML files. The problem is that those XML files do not always have the same format. So, i am writing a code in php5 and I would like to know how to count the number of occurences a specific child appear within a tag. In my XML file, i want to count the number of time the child "ing" appears within the node "ing-div". Some XML files can have one, two, or more "ing-div" node. Any Help?

here is the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <recipeml version="0.5">
- <recipe>
- <head>
  <title>100 Whole Wheat Bread for Bread Machine</title> 
- <categories>
  <cat>Breadmaker</cat> 
  <cat>Breads</cat> 
  </categories>
  <yield>8</yield> 
  </head>
- <ingredients>
- <ing-div>
  <title>REGULAR LOAF</title> 
- <ing>
- <amt>
  <qty>1</qty> 
  <unit>cup</unit> 
  </amt>
  <item>Water</item> 
  </ing>
- <ing>
- <amt>
  <qty>2 1/2</qty> 
  <unit>cups</unit> 
  </amt>
  <item>Wheat bread flour</item> 
  </ing>
- <ing>
- <amt>
  <qty>1 1/4</qty> 
  <unit>tablespoons</unit> 
  </amt>
  <item>Dry milk</item> 
  </ing>
- <ing>
- <amt>
  <qty>1</qty> 
  <unit>teaspoon</unit> 
  </amt>
  <item>Salt</item> 
  </ing>
- <ing>
- <amt>
  <qty>1 1/2</qty> 
  <unit>tablespoons</unit> 
  </amt>
  <item>Butter</item> 
  </ing>
- <ing>
- <amt>
  <qty>1 1/4</qty> 
  <unit>tablespoons</unit> 
  </amt>
  <item>Honey</item> 
  </ing>
- <ing>
- <amt>
  <qty>1</qty> 
  <unit>tablespoon</unit> 
  </amt>
  <item>Gluten</item> 
  </ing>
- <ing>
- <amt>
  <qty>2</qty> 
  <unit>teaspoons</unit> 
  </amt>
  <item>Molasses</item> 
  </ing>
- <ing>
- <amt>
  <qty>1 1/2</qty> 
  <unit>teaspoons</unit> 
  </amt>
  <item>Fast-Rise yeast *** OR ***</item> 
  </ing>
- <ing>
- <amt>
  <qty>2</qty> 
  <unit>teaspoons</unit> 
  </amt>
  <item>Active-Dry yeast</item> 
  </ing>
  </ing-div>
- <ing-div>
  <title>LARGE LOAF</title> 
- <ing>
- <amt>
  <qty>1 1/2</qty> 
  <unit>cups</unit> 
  </amt>
  <item>+ 2 tb Water</item> 
  </ing>
- <ing>
- <amt>
  <qty>3 3/4</qty> 
  <unit>cups</unit> 
  </amt>
  <item>Wheat bread flour</item> 
  </ing>
- <ing>
- <amt>
  <qty>2</qty> 
  <unit>tablespoons</unit> 
  </amt>
  <item>Dry milk</item> 
  </ing>
- <ing>
- <amt>
  <qty>1 1/2</qty> 
  <unit>teaspoons</unit> 
  </amt>
  <item>Salt</item> 
  </ing>
- <ing>
- <amt>
  <qty>2</qty> 
  <unit>tablespoons</unit> 
  </amt>
  <item>Butter</item> 
  </ing>
- <ing>
- <amt>
  <qty>2</qty> 
  <unit>tablespoons</unit> 
  </amt>
  <item>Honey</item> 
  </ing>
- <ing>
- <amt>
  <qty>1 1/2</qty> 
  <unit>tablespoons</unit> 
  </amt>
  <item>Gluten</item> 
  </ing>
- <ing>
- <amt>
  <qty>1</qty> 
  <unit>tablespoon</unit> 
  </amt>
  <item>Molasses</item> 
  </ing>
- <ing>
- <amt>
  <qty>2 1/8</qty> 
  <unit>teaspoons</unit> 
  </amt>
  <item>Fast-Rise yeast *** OR ***</item> 
  </ing>
- <ing>
- <amt>
  <qty>3</qty> 
  <unit>teaspoons</unit> 
  </amt>
  <item>Active-Dry yeast</item> 
  </ing>
  </ing-div>
  </ingredients>
- <directions>
  <step>The trick to making 100% whole wheat bread in your machine is an extra knead, which gives the yeast and gluten a second chance to create a lighter loaf. When your first knead cycle is completed, simply reset the machine and start again. Some manufacturers produce home bakeries with a whole wheat cycle; if your machine doesn't have one, this start- again method works as an easy alternative. SUCCESS HINTS: The gluten gives the whole wheat flour the structure necessary for a good loaf. If your market doesn't stock wheat gluten, try your local health food store. Remember the extra knead. It's especially important in 100% whole wheat bread. Because of the extra knead, us this recipe only on the regular bake cycle. CALORIES: 125 PROTEIN: 14% CHOLESTEROL: 3.98mg CARBOHYDRATES: 73% SODIUM: 218mg FAT: 13% Posted to Bakery-Shoppe Digest V1 #410 by serge.cyr@sympatico.ca (Serge Cyr) on Nov 23, 1997</step> 
  </directions>
  </recipe>
  </recipeml>
```

and this is part of the code where I am trying to count the number of occurences of "ing" within "ing-div"

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
$ing_elem = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
printf("%d ing.\n", $ing_elem->{'ing-div'}->count() );
```

but, it does not work at all. I have the error message:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in C:\wamp\www\PhP\Folder xml\New_Load_All_Files_1.php on line 115

anny suggestions?

thank you so much for your time and your help.

T3000

Comment: Are you sure you're loading the xml correctly? The error you're getting means Simple XML cannot read/parse the xml file. As it's written it expects `$file` to be a valid filepath to the xml file. Are you sure it's correct? If so, are you sure the xml is valid?

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load(path/to/file);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);
$ingdiv = $xpath->query("/recipeml/recipe/ingredients/ing-div");
$length = $ingdiv->length;
// iterate over all <ing-div> from last to first
while($length--)
{
    // number of <ing> in the specific <ing-div>
    print $xpath->query("ing", $ingdiv->item($length))->length;
}
```

Edit:

You should not Copy & Paste the formated output from a browser.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
- <recipeml/>
```

This is malformed XML. XML cannot have text outside the root node.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the following line:

```
$ing_elem = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
```

since you are using simplexml_load_file($file) to create a SimpleXMLElement object

So your simpleXML object can be created only using this line:

```
$ing_elem = simplexml_load_file($file);
```

You can use the following code fragment to get more information about errors which might occur:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$ing_elem = simplexml_load_file($file);
if (!$ing_elem) {
    echo "Failed loading XML\n";
    foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
        echo "\t", $error->message;
    }
}
```

Comment: but if idelete the line $ing_elem = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);  i will have a problem with the following line, because my variable $ing_elem will not be defined anymore.